# Interleave two wildcard commands

Tags: bash, unix

I'm quite new to the unix shell and could really use your help!

I have a script which produces plenty of .tex files of my C++ project, like so:

> a.h.tex a.cpp.tex b.h.tex b.cpp.tex ... etc.

I then run pdflatex on all of them and merge the resulting files into one using:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output merged_code.pdf
```

This works well but the wildcard matches files in alphabetical order, so I end up with the cpp files *before* the header files when I'd like to have them after them. I'd like to put my main file at the very end (or start), so:

> a.h.pdf then a.cpp.pdf then b.h.pdf then b.cpp.pdf ... main.cpp.pdf

rather than

> a.cpp.pdf then a.h.pdf then b.cpp.pdf then b.h.pdf ... main.cpp.pdf ...

I did quite a bit of research and tried to interleave the outputs of ls like this:

```
shopt -s extglob
paste -d '\n', <(ls *.h.pdf) <(!(main).cpp.pdf
```

as an input, but though it looked promising, it ultimately didn't work, so I'd be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Do you want all *.h first, followed by all *.cpp followed by main.cpp? or pair of .h and .cpp followed by next pair of .h and .cpp?

Comment: pair of .h and .cpp followed by next pair is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob
echo $(paste <(ls *.h.pdf) <(ls !(main).cpp.pdf main*))
```

---

I would say you found the answer by yourself. I practically just took the code in your example and added `main*`.
Credits to you.

---

#### Example

```
$ ls
a.cpp.pdf  a.h.pdf  b.cpp.pdf  b.h.pdf  main.cpp.pdf

$ echo $(paste <(ls *.h.pdf) <(ls !(main).cpp.pdf main*))
a.h.pdf a.cpp.pdf b.h.pdf b.cpp.pdf main.cpp.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

Your paste attempt was pretty close. I think the problem was just that paste expects lines and you weren't splitting the inputs into lines.

Try this:

```
$ ls
a.cpp.pdf  b.h.pdf    d.cpp.pdf     r.cpp.pdf  s.h.pdf
a.h.pdf    c.cpp.pdf  d.h.pdf       r.h.pdf    t.cpp.pdf
b.cpp.pdf  c.h.pdf    main.cpp.pdf  s.cpp.pdf  t.h.pdf
$ echo $(paste <(echo *.h.pdf | tr ' ' '\n') <(echo !(main*).cpp.pdf | tr ' ' '\n')) main.pdf
a.h.pdf a.cpp.pdf b.h.pdf b.cpp.pdf c.h.pdf c.cpp.pdf d.h.pdf d.cpp.pdf r.h.pdf r.cpp.pdf s.h.pdf s.cpp.pdf t.h.pdf t.cpp.pdf main.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It works, too, but I accepted jaba's in the end because it was so close to mine and I checked it first. Sorry about that!

Comment: @noctilux No worries. It should be pointed out though, just for completeness' sake, that neither of these solutions is safe in the face of files with spaces/etc. in their names.